# How to solve iso image mount?

Tags: 14.04, partitioning, mount, fsck

```
root@milenko-HP-Compaq-6830s:/home/milenko/2014a# mount -o loop MATLAB\ R2014a\ Unix.iso /mnt/iso  
mount: you must specify the filesystem type
```

Here is what I got with parted -l

```
Model: ATA FUJITSU MHZ2250B (scsi) Disk /dev/sda: 250GB Sector size
(logical/physical): 512B/512B Partition Table: msdos

Number  Start   End    Size    Type      File system     Flags  1     
1049kB  248GB  248GB   primary   ext4            boot  2      248GB  
250GB  2140MB  extended  5      248GB   250GB  2140MB  logical  
linux-swap(v1)

fsck from util-linux 2.20.1 e2fsck 1.42.9 (4-Feb-2014) /dev/sda1 is
mounted. e2fsck: Cannot continue, aborting.
```

What should I do next?

---

Inside 2014a folder,there is another install.jar folder.The instruction (readme.txt) tells me that I should copy this install.jar folder to MATLAB R2014a Unix.iso.

---

Ok,I have followed your advices.

```
> milenko@milenko-HP-Compaq-6830s:~$ df -h /mnt/iso/ 
> Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on 
> /dev/sda1       228G   63G  154G  29%
> 




> milenko@milenko-HP-Compaq-6830s:~$ ls -l  /mnt/iso
 total 0
```

Regarding MATLAB code,no it is not a zip archive.

Comment: Is this a legal copy of the MATLAB software?

Comment: No,my friend gave me.

Comment: Have a look at `man mount`, especially where the `-t` switch is explained.

Comment: Post the output of `file MATLAB\ R2014a\ Unix.iso` and/or try `sudo mount -o loop -t iso9660 MATLAB\ R2014a\ Unix.iso /mnt/iso`

Comment: file MATLAB\ R2014a\ Unix.iso 
MATLAB R2014a Unix.iso: Java Jar file data (zip)

Comment: Then:
mount: block device /home/milenko/2014a/MATLAB R2014a Unix.iso is write-protected, mounting read-only
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/loop1,
       missing codepage or helper program, or other error
       In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
       dmesg | tail  or so

Comment: try `-t udf` as well.

Comment: Gives me same with -t udf.

Comment: can you past the out put of following command "ls -l /mnt/iso"

Comment: Sound like the file is a zip archive. What do you get from `unzip -t MATLAB\ R2014a\ Unix.iso`?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the poster admitted the question relates to pirated software.

Comment: @RodSmith: private software copies (incl. those from friends) are legal in many jurisdictions (e. g. mine).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check where the /mnt folder is mounted and check?
can check it with command 
`df -h`
OR
`mount`
and post your output this will help to solve your problem soon.

The error tells that /mnt/iso folder is not formatted to a filesystem.

OR
Try mounting it using a GUI.

Navigate to the *.iso file using a file manager, then  Right click -> Open with Archive Mounter.

Or

you can install the Furius ISO mount. It is available in the Ubuntu Software Center
sudo apt-get install furiusisomount

Comment: I have installed  Furius ISO mount.But...

Comment: It does not work properly.

Comment: Did you tried to Open the iso with furius iso mount? try `# mount -o loop MATLAB\ R2014a\ Unix.iso /mnt`